# Suppress "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

Tags: ssh

I would like to suppress this message:

> X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

And I want to suppress only this particular message (I don't want to run in quite mode).

Is there a way to configure open-ssh like this?

Comment: Dear down-voters: Please tell me what's wrong with this question. I love to read comments and hints. Thank your very much.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- Disable the request for X forwarding (e.g. don't use the `-X` or `-Y` switches for `ssh` or disable it in `~/.ssh/config` (or even the global config...
- install `xauth` on the remote machine

That doesn't supress the message, it fixes the underlying problem....